# getting encrypted value while fetching website using LWP

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

I am getting encrypted data when fetching the contents of a web site. How to overcome that issue?

Here is my script.

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent( "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0" );

my $url = "website url";

my $req = HTTP::Request->new( GET => "$url" );
my $res = $ua->request( $req );

my $content = $res->content;

print $content;
```

Comment: getting output like this
rx¦Qe9­¡¨Ž¼¿Á½~¸×îýà¶Q ²6ÙÜ¸¶úÛ’° ï’m‘/³E½$é
"÷ vë¨{óo²è£ÅÜNWæ-uM…€¾¡Ú•í±ùLU×‚»‘a^\æt9q¿Â}CàÃ·¸Á¡3Ü¡4ïë‘#9_¦4_HN,

Comment: Looks like the content is **encoded**, not encrypted. Use `$res->decoded_content` instead of `$res->content` to decode it. This is a normal part of how the web works. Could be _deflate_ or _gzip_. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression for how this stuff works under the hood.

Comment: @simbabque: You should post an answer

Comment: @Borodin I think that should suffice.

Comment: @Micro: Please make sure to *always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of *every* Perl program that you write.

Answer (score 3):

Your output is not **encrypted**, [it's **encoded**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression). That's a normal way to make messages on the web smaller. Think of a ZIP file that takes less space to put on a floppy disk<sup>1</sup>.

Luckily, [HTTP::Response](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response) provides the `decoded_content` method that does all the decoding magic for you. Simply replace `$res->content` with `$res->decoded_content`.

```
my $res = $ua->get($url);
my $content = $res->decoded_content;
```

This will just give you the decoded content. You don't need to bother about what kind of encoding was used. Common ones are *gzip* or *deflate*, but you usually don't need to worry about that at all.

If you're curious, you can [`dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Message#$mess-%3Edump(-%25opt-)) the whole response to see the headers as well as the (escaped) content in a text representation.

```
$res->dump;
```

The SYNOPSIS of the documentation of [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) actually shows this, too.

> ```
> use strict;
> use warnings;
> use LWP::UserAgent ();
>
> my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
> $ua->timeout(10);
> $ua->env_proxy;
>
> my $response = $ua->get('http://search.cpan.org/');
>
> if ($response->is_success) {
>     print $response->decoded_content;  # or whatever
> }
> else {
>     die $response->status_line;
> }
> ```

---

<sup>1) for those of us who remember what that is. For everyone else: the things that look like the *save as* icon</sup>